# SQL - Result consisted of more than one row

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I'm still trying to make my first function, it creates without any errors, but when I try to use it, it gives me error - ERROR 1172 (42000): Result consisted of more than one row

Here's the function -

```
CREATE FUNCTION kontakti2 (mainigais CHAR(3)) 
RETURNS CHAR(100) 
BEGIN 
DECLARE returnthis CHAR(100); 
SELECT CONCAT(Person.name, Person.lastName, Contacts.mobile, Contacts.email) 
FROM Person JOIN Contacts on Contacts.Person_ID = Person.ID 
JOIN ParentChild on ParentChild.parentID = Person.ID 
JOIN ChildGroup ON ChildGroup.Person_ID = ParentChild.childID 
WHERE ChildGroup.Group_ID = mainigais INTO returnthis; 
RETURN returnthis; 
END//
```

Here's table schema, just in case - http://www.imagesup.net/dm-713886347846.png

How can I get this function to display several rows?

Comment: You want to use a stored procedure, not a function. Read up about the differences.

Comment: You just filter on a whole group, so you might have more than one row. As this function return only 1 CHAR(100) you should return only 1 row (i.e. 1 user).

Comment: @fancyPants can't, it's homework and I need function for it.

Comment: Your current function looks to be attempting to return the contact details for each person in a group. Is that the plan? At the moment you're getting one result row per person, rather than a single `char(100)`. SQL Server supports table valued functions, (ie multiple row). Not sure if MySql does though.

Comment: @JonEgerton Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. And I'm pretty sure it is MySql server.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to return multiple rows from a function in MySQL as it does not support table valued functions like in SQL server.